# Postgresql - change foreign key to another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
create table test1 (
oldPrimaryKey varchar(100) primary key, 
someText varchar(100)
)

create table test2 (
someText varchar(100),
 oldPrimaryKey varchar(100) references test1(oldPrimaryKey)
)
```

I need to change `oldPrimaryKey` to new one so I do this:

1. Drop old one key:

   - alter table test1 drop constraint test1_pkey;
   - alter table test2 drop constraint test2_oldprimarykey_fkey;
2. Create new column:

   - alter table test1 add column newPrimaryKey bigint;
3. Populate it using sequence:

   - create sequence add_id_seq start with 1 increment by 1 cache 1;
   - update test1 set newPrimaryKey = nextval('add_id_seq');
4. Change “newPrimaryKey” column to be primary key:

   - alter table test1 add constraint keyName primary key(newPrimaryKey);

Now I have something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test1
(
  oldprimarykey character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  sometext character varying(100),
  newprimarykey bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT keyname PRIMARY KEY (newprimarykey)
)

CREATE TABLE test2
(
  sometext character varying(100),
  oldprimarykey character varying(100),
  CONSTRAINT test2_oldprimarykey_fkey FOREIGN KEY (oldprimarykey)
      REFERENCES test1 (oldprimarykey) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I don’t know what to do now (some script?). I need to change value from table `test2` column `oldprimarykey` to corresponding value from table `test1` column `newprimarykey`.

If it is too chaotic I will try to give an example of the normal data:

Rows from table1 (oldprimarykey, sometext, newprimarykey):

1. test@test.com, ‘some text’, 1
2. test2@test.com, ‘more text’, 2

Corresponding  rows from table2 (sometext, oldprimarykey):

1. ‘some text’, test@test.com
2. ‘text text’, test2test.com

I want to change email adress from table2 to corresponding  int from table1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
update test2
  set newprimarykey = t1.newprimarykey
from test1 t1
where t1.oldprimarykey = test2.oldprimarykey;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e558a/1